# (C) Using strings to read in values, then sperate and tokenize them

Tags: c, string, token, tokenize

I'm having an issue with converting my code's scanning to use strings, and currently it causes the command prompt to crash. If there's any extra info that would make this easier, let me know. Thanks for any of your help.

Input (a .csv comma seperated variable spreadsheet):

```
PART    2       -1    0.05      V
PART    0.975   -1    0.025     V
PART    3        1    0.01      F
GAP     0        0.08
```

My attempt with strings:

```
char ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,c[3],line[100],*n[100],s[3]=",",*token;
float nom[3],impct[3],tol[3],gapmin,gapmax,tolerance,max_gap,min_gap,gap;
int i;
// ---------------------
char keyPart[] = "PART";
char keyGAP[] = "GAP";
// ----------------------

if (fpin==NULL)     //error checking for file
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);      //close files
}
while ( fgets(line, 100, fpin) != NULL )
{
    strcpy(n, line);
    token = strtok(line,s);
    // -----------------
    if (strcmp(keyPart, token) == 0)
    {
        // PART
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL,s);
            nom[i] = strtof(token, NULL);
            token = strtok(NULL,s);
            impct[i] = strtof(token, NULL);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(keyGAP, token) == 0)
    {
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            token=strtok(NULL,s);
            gapmin=strtof(token, NULL);// GAP
            token= strtok(NULL,s);
            gapmax= strtof(token, NULL);
        }
    }
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL,s);
    }
}
```

My code before strings (functions properly)

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)    //loop to scan in values
{
    fscanf(fpin,"%c%c%c%c,",&ch1,&ch2,&ch3,&ch4);     //scan in four characters

    if (ch1=='P' && ch2=='A' && ch3=='R' && ch4=='T' )    //If the characters spell PART...
    {
        fscanf(fpin,"%f,%f,%f,%c\n", &nom[i],&impct[i],&tol[i],&c[i]);   //scan in values
        printf("%f,%f,%f,%c\n",nom[i],impct[i],tol[i],c[i]); //print the values
    }

    if(ch1=='G' && ch2=='A' && ch3=='P')     //If Characters spell GAP...
    {
        fscanf(fpin,"%f,%f",&gapmin,&gapmax);   //scan in values
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Eliminates crash at least right now:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL,s);
            nom[i] = strtof(token, NULL);
            //token = strtok(NULL,s);
            impct[i] = strtof(token, NULL);
            //printf("\n%f\n%f\n",nom[i],impct[i]);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(keyGAP, token) == 0)
    {

            token=strtok(NULL,s);
            gapmin=strtof(token, NULL);// GAP
            //token= strtok(NULL,s);
            gapmax= strtof(token, NULL);
            //printf("\n%f\n%f\n",gapmin,gapmax);

    }
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL,s);
        printf("%s\n", token);

    }
}
```

Comment: over execute `strtok`. You are running more than the number of fields.

Comment: Changed the code so it at least doesn't crash, check the bottom of the question for the edit.

Comment: Am I missing something as to why this is a big mystery?  Each line has 3 numbers, when you find "PART" you `strtok` 3 times in the "good" version and 6 times in the "bad" version, never checking for NULL.  You will dump when you `strtof` NULL.